# where is 'my.cnf' file in Linux?

Tags: linux

I'm setting MariaDB with Linux up.
And I was going to edit property "bind-address" to accept external connection.
So I need to edit 'my.cnf' file. I found this file and tried to "vi my.cnf" and my linux shows [image]

where can I find "bind_address" property and edit it?
Did i find right file?

Answer (score 2):

From the last two lines in this file, you can see that it loads all the files in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/` and `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/`. So you also have to look in those directories for a files that have a "bind-address" line.

You can look for "bind-address" automatically using the following command:

```
grep -r 'bind-address' /etc/mysql/conf.d/ /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

This command looks for lines containing "bind-address" in all the files in each directory, and for each matching line it will print the filename and the line. You can then edit the files that it finds using your favourite text editor.